# Grid 960 looks different in ie8 and ff9

Tags: internet-explorer-8, grid, 960.gs

i have the following simple grid960 HTML code: http://pastebin.com/m1SYMH5S
but it looks verry different in ie8 and FF9, what have i done wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your doctype declaration is incomplete. It should be

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: You dont have to use HTML5 for 960gs. You just need to correct your doctype declaration, as shown above.